# top x% font size is small

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

Before the redesign of the profile page the font size for top x% this period is bigger and was not superscript.

[image]

Can top x% this period have the same font size as Reputation and share the same baseline with Reputation?

[image]

Comment: I definitely pops more with the larger font.

Comment: It'd be even nicer if the title and "top..." shared the same baseline.

Comment: I don't care about the size, but the alignment is kind of awkward in that shot.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah of course forgot to mention it. Updated the question.